# how to add block IP to CSF by PHP

Tags: php, linux

i would like to add IP to black list CSF Linux server by PHP code.any body help me?

```
$cmd = "sudo /usr/sbin/csf -d";
$s = $cmd . " " . $ip . " " . $comment;
$output = shell_exec($s);
```

i used this code but not working.event run in Cron jobs.

Comment: Nice code. Do you know why PHP is never run as root?

Comment: but not work,why?